# Some Q2A plugins are not compatible with PhP 7 and MySQL 5.7

Tags: plugins, php-7, mysql-5.7, question2answer

I updated PHP 5.6 to 7 and MySQL 5.5 to 5.7.

Everything was fine in the older versions, however since I updated the server some plugins such as: Custom 404 page, gregorian2jalali face problems. Some pages goes blank and the Inspect Element, Console section nothing shows. up. For example, if I activate gregorian2jalali plugin, User Profie page doesn't show up.

Also in the Custom 404 page plugin, the following error comes up in 404 pages:

A Question2Answer database query failed when generating this page. A full description of the failure is available in the web server's error log file.
There was a related question for an earlier problem here: [When adding page link, database query error occurs.](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/24797/when-adding-page-link-database-query-error-occurs)

In the Apache Error Log, a message similar to this message comes up:

PHP Question2Answer MySQL query error 1146: Table 'qa.qa_options' doesn't exist - Query: (SELECT 'options' AS selectkey, title, content FROM qa_options) UNION ALL (SELECT 'time', 'db_time', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
Also, there was an earlier problem here at this question: [is there a way to manually create the database tables ?](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/40075/is-there-a-way-to-manually-create-the-database-tables)

Now that the plugin is not updated, how I can fix this problem ?

Thanks

Q2A version: 1.7.4

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. You are using a different table prefix (e.g. `abc_` instead of `qa_`) in your `qa-config.php` file, and a plugin is putting `qa_options` in their SQL queries instead of `^options` as they should (which automatically adds the correct prefix).
2. Or, you are using the unstable 1.8 version from GitHub which currently has a few issues regarding plugins. If so, make sure you're using the stable 1.7.4 version that you get from the [main Q2A site](http://www.question2answer.org/).